# how to get fixed html from an arbitrary html string

Tags: javascript, dom

**Overview**

I'm trying to highlight a dom range and then unhighlight it. Given that a range can span multiple elements, even block elements, wrapping a range in a span with a highlighter class can disrupt the appearance of the page. What's worse, I have not discovered a clean way to reverse the operation. `range.extractContents()` is the only method that I know of that will fix the html to ensure tags are closed properly, but it alters the document by inserting shim nodes around the "span" that remain after I remove the "span".

My idea to work around this is to use another approach. I could replace the html of the most common ancestor with new html that contains my span. Then save the original html and restore it to accomplish the "unhighlight". 
I think this will work to solve the undo-ability issue, but i don't know how to fix the html in the same way `range.extractContents()` fixes it.

Is there a method that will take html and "fix it" to be suitable as the right hand side for an assignment to `innerHtml`?

Comment: Assigning to `innerHTML` implicitly involves using HTML parser, so syntax errors in the assigned code are fixed automatically — just assign to `innerHTML` and read it back to get the fixed code. You may also use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Comment: @MaratTanalin, my question was very narrow in scope, and your comment is actually the precise answer to my very precise question, if you want to answer.

Comment: Ok, posted the comment (with a small addition) as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning to `innerHTML` implicitly involves using HTML parser, so syntax errors in the assigned code are fixed automatically — just assign to `innerHTML` and read it back to get the fixed code. You may also use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Note that such fixed code may not necessarily be what you expect in each specific case.

Answer (score 1):

The *least invasive* method would be getting the text nodes of the range, calculating `.getBoxQuads()` on each range and then inserting absolutely positioned overlays with [CSS filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) over those coordinates.

Comment: This is a good idea for not messing up the dom. I have currently settled on a third solution which is to simply add the range to the page selection (make it selected), then style the selection with `::selection`. But I'm about to investigate a *4th* solution which would be to use `document.execCommand()` over the range! Your idea is not bad and if I want borders and to not mess with the dom I may need to use it. There is also "dom shadowing" which I just heard about last night  but I don't know if that can do a perfect job.